# How can I remove default banner of web server from response - Apache http1.1 coyote

Tags: http, header

Please let me know how can I remove default banner of web server from response - Apache http1.1 coyote

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the generated line at the bottom of apache generated pages, you have to update your httpd.conf with this command:

```
ServerSignature Off
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serversignature

Be careful, theses informations are also sent through HTTP headers. You can alter them via this [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens)

About Coyote, AFAIK there is no key to hide these info.

Answer (score 0):

In server.xml there will be a `<Connector>` element.  Add a `server` attribute to it.  For example:

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
    port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    server=" "
    ...
/>
```

Unfortunately, setting the `server` attribute to an empty string doesn't cause any change in behavior.  Setting `server` to a string with a single space results in a header like:

```
Server:
```

While not optimal, it's progress.